# Server running on Windows 10 as a service, OWIN self-hosted with WebAPI endpoints making an SSL connection without configuring a private key

Tags: ssl

I have created a prototype application the runs on Windows 10 that communicates with a server (described in the title) running as a service on a different system and successfully got SSL working but I'm missing something because I never seemed to generate any keys. I only just self-taught myself how to use PowerShell to create the self-signed certificate (so bare with me) using New-SelfSignedCertificate but I have very little insight into why this worked at all. From my very limited understanding a private key on the server is absolutely required for SSL to work, and I never associated one with my certificate... but it's working and I think I'm fooling myself.

All I did was create the certificate with `New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=My Server Name"`
Then add the binding with `netsh http add sslcert certhash=<the thumbprint> appid={the app id}`
And add the reservation for the service with `netsh http add urlacl url="https://+:<my port number>/" user='NT AUTHORITY\LocalService'`

This all works, but I'm not sure I understand how because I never configured a private key. I know it must need to be expanded upon somehow to make it more secure because every single tutorial out there talks about making the certificate trustworthy and assigning a private key to the cert... but I've done none of that and it still appears to work. Granted, the client is not a web browser and will never care about the authenticity of the server because of the context in which this particular application will run (It's to connect scientific components together in a lab, and there's almost no exposure outside the network).

What am I missing here? Did Windows 10 provide a private key anyway? How can it really be encrypted if I didn't need to specify these things? I also never moved the certificate to a trusted store of any kind because it frankly didn't seem necessary since the client is just a proprietary front-end application.

Comment: You created it with `New-SelfSignedCertificate`. See the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps).